# Possible values for msrp_display_actual_price_type in Magento API

Tags: api, magento

What are the possible values for `msrp_display_actual_price_type` in the Magento API. It takes an Int, but I haven't been able to find any documentation that tells what values are mapped to the UI, or how I might do a lookup to get those values.

Answer (score 3):

A quick inspection of the admin panel and the field on a product edit screen, in the 'Prices' tab is 'Display Actual Price' and the values are:

```
1 = On Gesture
2 = In Cart
3 = Before Order Confirmation
4 = Use config
```

More information here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html

I know this has been hanging around a while but I had the same questions, found this and then found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on CSV import which I resolved by replacing in the spreadsheet the msrp_display_actual_price_type value as follows:

Relaced: 4
with: Use config